# OPcache php5.5 on DirectAdmin disabled

Tags: php, opcache

I installed php5.5 to my CentOS DirectAdmin server.

I used this http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=567 to install OPcache en set it to yes.

I did enable OPcache also in my php.ini file with opcache.enable=1.

But when I check my phpinfo() it is displayed like this:

[image]

So is it enabled now or not, because Opcode Caching is disabled but opcache.enable is On?

All changes I made in the php.ini file, are saved and I see them in my phpinfo(). But Opcode Caching is still disabled.

Comment: Did you restart PHP so that config is reloaded? Are you sure you dedited correct php.ini file? phpinfo() output should tell you which file it is using.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Yes I did restart PHP and I checked the correct php.ini file. I edit that php.ini file, but I still do see this result

Comment: Just to be clear, did you restart the web server (ie Apache?).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you edited wrong php.ini file!
try to find your php.ini file with this command `/usr/local/bin/php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'`